# C# WebClient crashes my application!

Tags: c#, .net, download, webclient

i'm trying to run this code:

```
remoteProducts.ForEach(delegate(RemoteProduct p)
                {
                    this.toolStripStatus.Text = "Downloading product: " + this.progress.Value + "/" + remoteProducts.Count;

                    try
                    {
                        prodLocalDao.addProduct(p.Id, p.Category, p.SubCategory, p.Sku);
                        int localProductId = p.Id;

                        List<ProductAttribute> attributes = prodRemoteDao.getProductAttributesByProductId(p.Id);
                        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Count; i++)
                        {
                            prodLocalDao.addAttribute(localProductId, attributes[i].Id, attributes[i].Name, attributes[i].Value);
                        }

                        // Add photos
                        ArrayList photos = prodRemoteDao.getPhotosFromRemoteByProductId(p.Id);
                        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(String.Format("photos\\{0}\\", p.Id));
                        if (!directory.Exists) directory.Create();

                        for (int i = 0; i < photos.Count; i++)
                        {
                            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(photos[i].ToString());
                            this.DownloadFTP(photos[i].ToString(), directory.FullName + file.Name);
                        }

                        this.toolStripStatus.Text += "... Done";
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        this.toolStripStatus.Text += "... Skiped";
                    }


                    this.progress.Value++;
                    this.Refresh();
                });
```

And it downloads images for the first product correctly, yet when it tries to run this line for the second product:

```
prodLocalDao.addProduct(p.Id, p.Category, p.SubCategory, p.Sku);
```

it crashes my application saying vhost has stopped working and these are the details it shows:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event
>   Name: APPCRASH   Application
>   Name: Desktop Manager.vshost.exe
>   Application Version:  9.0.21022.8
>   Application Timestamp:    47316898
>   Fault Module Name:    winhttp.dll   Fault
>   Module Version:   6.1.7600.16385   Fault
>   Module Timestamp: 4a5bdb3e   Exception
>   Code: c0000005   Exception
>   Offset:   000015cb   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1   Locale
>   ID:   1033   Additional Information
>   1:    0a9e   Additional Information
>   2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>   Additional Information 3: 0a9e
>   Additional Information
>   4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not
>   available, please read our privacy
>   statement offline:
>   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

**DownloadFtp Function**

```
public void DownloadFTP(string RemotePath, string LocalPath)
        {
            BasicFTPClient MyClient = new BasicFTPClient();
            MyClient.Host = Desktop_Manager.Properties.Settings.Default["ftphost"].ToString();
            MyClient.Username = Desktop_Manager.Properties.Settings.Default["ftpuser"].ToString();
            MyClient.Password = Desktop_Manager.Properties.Settings.Default["ftppass"].ToString();


            string remotePath = String.Format("/media/catalog/product{0}", RemotePath);
            MyClient.DownloadFile(remotePath, LocalPath);
        }
```

**And now the BasicFTPClient Class**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace BasicFTPClientNamespace
{
    class BasicFTPClient
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
        public string Host;
        public int Port;

        public BasicFTPClient()
        {
            Username = "anonymous";
            Password = "anonymous@internet.com";
            Port = 21;
            Host = "";
        }

        public BasicFTPClient(string theUser, string thePassword, string theHost)
        {
            Username = theUser;
            Password = thePassword;
            Host = theHost;
            Port = 21;
        }

        private Uri BuildServerUri(string Path)
        {
            return new Uri(String.Format("ftp://{0}:{1}/{2}", Host, Port, Path));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method downloads the given file name from the FTP server
        /// and returns a byte array containing its contents.
        /// Throws a WebException on encountering a network error.
        /// </summary>

        public byte[] DownloadData(string path)
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            WebClient request = new WebClient();

            // Logon to the server using username + password
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            return request.DownloadData(BuildServerUri(path));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method downloads the FTP file specified by "ftppath" and saves
        /// it to "destfile".
        /// Throws a WebException on encountering a network error.
        /// </summary>
        public void DownloadFile(string ftppath, string destfile)
        {
            // Download the data
            byte[] Data = DownloadData(ftppath);

            // Save the data to disk
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(destfile, FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Upload a byte[] to the FTP server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">Path on the FTP server (upload/myfile.txt)</param>
        /// <param name="Data">A byte[] containing the data to upload</param>
        /// <returns>The server response in a byte[]</returns>

        public byte[] UploadData(string path, byte[] Data)
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            WebClient request = new WebClient();

            // Logon to the server using username + password
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            return request.UploadData(BuildServerUri(path), Data);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load a file from disk and upload it to the FTP server
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ftppath">Path on the FTP server (/upload/myfile.txt)</param>
        /// <param name="srcfile">File on the local harddisk to upload</param>
        /// <returns>The server response in a byte[]</returns>

        public byte[] UploadFile(string ftppath, string srcfile)
        {
            // Read the data from disk
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(srcfile, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] FileData = new byte[fs.Length];

            int numBytesToRead = (int)fs.Length;
            int numBytesRead = 0;
            while (numBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                int n = fs.Read(FileData, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                // Break when the end of the file is reached.
                if (n == 0) break;

                numBytesRead += n;
                numBytesToRead -= n;
            }
            numBytesToRead = FileData.Length;
            fs.Close();

            // Upload the data from the buffer
            return UploadData(ftppath, FileData);
        }

    }
}
```

Any ideas why??!!

thanks...

Comment: Please try to cut this down to a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. A lot of the code shown here is probably irrelevant. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: please, i don;t know how to write this better... it's a simple foreach loop which runs a simple download on a webclient class. I tried to post as little as could about the code. And i illustrated that the problem was indeed on the winhttp.dll with the last error mensaje. When you said "short but complete program which demonstrates the problem", you meant that i should upload a binary with this problem?

Comment: I have trouble finding the WebClient.

Comment: "i don't know how to write this better: -> In VS, use File|NewProject and write a simple for-loop that downloads files with a webclient. Make it more an more like your app until you can reproduce the error.

Comment: Can you paste the code to downloadFTP() ? From the error message, it seems as if the crash occured in winhttp.dll. Where are you running this code? Is it a console application, winforms app, or asp.net app?

Comment: it's a winforms app, i'm also writing the code for the downloadFtp function. Thanks...